# How are local variables symbolized on the stack?

Tags: c, variables, stack

Local variables of the functions are stored on the stack. Every time we call a function, its local variables have a different address. How, behind the scenes, does OS/microcontroller knows that this particular variable is sitting at this address when we change the variable value?

Comment: are you asking about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)?

Comment: The short answer is that each function has a stack frame - that is an area of the stack reserved on entry for the locals and released again when the function returns. On Intel systems EBP/RBP, ESP/RSP are used to reference data relative to the current stack frame.

Comment: Because the local variable is *relative* to the stack, which isn't always the same on each run. The relative position is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

In typical C implementations, local variables are addressed relative to a stack pointer or frame pointer.

A hardware stack is a region of memory set aside for the purpose of maintaining data local to functions, as each function is called. A stack pointer or frame pointer in a register in the CPU that is used to hold an address for the currently active portion of the stack. When a function is called, the stack pointer or the frame pointer or both are adjusted to point to new space. The function stores its data on the stack by using offsets from the stack pointer or the frame pointer.

As the compiler processes the source code for a function, it plans the layout of data on the stack for that function. It knows the offsets of each object relative to the stack frame for the function, and it generates instructions using the appropriate offsets from the pointer registers.

The software that performs the initial loading of a program allocates memory for the hardware stack and initializes the stack pointer and/or frame pointer to point to it.